# How can I get a field with another field which is set foreign key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, prisma

schema.prisma:

```
model User {
  id         Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String        // Not Null
  self       Friend[]      @relation("self")   
  friend     Friend[]      @relation("friend")  
}

model Friend {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  user       User       @relation("self", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     Int        // Foreign Key
  friend     User       @relation("friend", fields: [friendId], references: [id])
  friendId   Int        // Foreign Key
  // @@unique([userId, friendID]) 
}
```

sample.tsx:

```
const friends = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: userId, // user ID
  },
  select: {
    name: true, // user name
    // Friend Table
    friend: {
      select: {
        userId: true, // friends' ID
      },
    },
  },
});

console.log(friends);
```

In sample.tsx I got :

```
{  
  name: 'Paul McCartney',
  friend: [ { userId: 1 }, { userId: 3 }, { userId: 4 } ]
}
```

I'd like to have not only user's name, in this case "Paul McCartney", but also friend's id and name :

```
{  
  name: 'Paul McCartney',
  friend: [ { userId: 1 , name: "John Lennon"}, { userId: 3, name: "Ringo starr" }, { userId: 4, name: "George Harrison" } ]
}

// OR something like...

{  
  name: 'Paul McCartney',
  {
    friend: [ { userId: 1}, { userId: 3 }, { userId: 4 } ],
    name: ["John Lennon", "Ringo starr", "George Harrison"]
  }
}
```

How should I change sample.tsx?

Prisma : 4.16.0
SQLite : 3.38.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const friends = await prisma.user.findUnique({
where: {
  id: userId, // user ID
},
select: {
  name: true, // user name
  friend: {
    select: {
      user: {
        select: {
          id: true, 
          name: true 
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
});

console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown field 'name' for select statement on model Friend

Of course cause Friend doesnt have the name prop you have to get the name from its user prop, basically you have to do this:

```js
const friends = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: userId, // user ID
  },
  select: {
    name: true, // user name
    friend: {
      select: {
        userId: true, // friends' ID
        user: {
          select:{
           name: true, // friends' name
         }
      },
    },
  },
});

console.log(friends);
```

which should return sth like:

```js
{  
  name: 'Paul McCartney',
  {
    friend: [ 
     { userId: 1, user: {name: "Manny"} },
     { userId: 3, user: {name: "Jane" } } 
    ],
  }
}
```